# SQL Sub-select as field?

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions, group-concat

I'm a bit lost here...

I have several tables I'd like to pull a unified record from: `Unit`, `Building`, `Owner`, and `Picture`.

Here's  my query so far:

```
SELECT building.`Street_Address`
    , building.`Building_Name`
    , building.`Building_Type`
    , CONCAT(building.`Cross_Street_1`, ' & ', building.`Cross_Street_2`) Cross_Streets
    , building.`Cross_Street_1`
    , building.`Cross_Street_2`
    , building.`Access` Building_Access
    , owner.`Company_Name`
    , owner.`Contact_Or_Reference`
    , owner.`Landlord_Phone`
    , picture.`Path_To_Picture_On_Server`
    , picture.`Picture_Category`
    , unit.`Apartment_Number`
    , unit.`Unit_Size_Number` Size
    , unit.`Is_Doorman`
    , unit.`Is_Furnished`
    , unit.`Is_Elevator`
    , unit.`Is_Pets`
    , unit.`Is_OutdoorSpace`
    , unit.`Rent_Price`
    , unit.`Baths`
    , unit.`Access` Unit_Access
    , unit.`fourd_id`
    , unit.`Updated_Date`
    , unit.`Occupancy_Date`
    , unit.`Term`
    , unit.`Incentives`
    , unit.`Info_OutdoorSpace`
    , unit.`List_Date`
    , zone.`Description`
FROM 4D_Units unit
JOIN 4D_Building building
    ON unit.`BUILDING_RecID` = building.`fourd_id`
JOIN 4D_Zones zone
    ON building.`ZONES_RecID` = zone.`fourd_id`
LEFT JOIN 4D_Owners owner
    ON unit.`OWNER_RecID` = owner.`fourd_id`
LEFT JOIN 4D_Building_Picts picture
    ON (building.`fourd_id` = picture.`BUILDING_RecID` AND picture.`Picture_Category` = 'Front')
WHERE unit.`id` = 49901
```

This works fine as-is, except that the return record will only ever have the "Front" picture in the record (if present). My issue is that there are several different types of photos that could be associated with a return record, including 'Panorama', 'Interior', and 'Floorplan'... all are different possible values for `picture.Picture_Category`.

Is there a way to return those values (if they are present, as above) in the returned set without doing a separate query? I want the returned set to include (if present) aliased values for all four possible options of `picture.Picture_Category`: 'Front', 'Panorama', 'Interior', & 'Floorplan' (with their own unique `picture.Path_To_Picture_On_Server` associated with it).

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have 4 sets of picture columns in your result set - one of reach of 4 categories? Right now you have just one for front, right?

You can join to the same table multiple times with different aliases and different join clauses. Just join to 4D_Building_Picts 4 times, once for each picture you want.

```
select 
    --whatever
    , pic_front.`Path_To_Picture_On_Server` AS Front_Path_To_Picture_On_Server
    , pic_panorama.`Path_To_Picture_On_Server` AS Panorama_Path_To_Picture_On_Server
    , pic_interior.`Path_To_Picture_On_Server` AS Interior_Path_To_Picture_On_Server
    , pic_floorplan.`Path_To_Picture_On_Server` AS Floorplan_Path_To_Picture_On_Server
    --whatever
FROM 4D_Units unit
JOIN 4D_Building building
    ON unit.`BUILDING_RecID` = building.`fourd_id`
JOIN 4D_Zones zone
    ON building.`ZONES_RecID` = zone.`fourd_id`
LEFT JOIN 4D_Owners owner
    ON unit.`OWNER_RecID` = owner.`fourd_id`
LEFT JOIN 4D_Building_Picts pic_front
    ON (building.`fourd_id` = pic_front.`BUILDING_RecID` AND pic_front.`Picture_Category` = 'Front')
LEFT JOIN 4D_Building_Picts pic_panorama
    ON (building.`fourd_id` = pic_panorama.`BUILDING_RecID` AND pic_panorama.`Picture_Category` = 'Panorama')
LEFT JOIN 4D_Building_Picts pic_interior
    ON (building.`fourd_id` = pic_interior.`BUILDING_RecID` AND pic_interior.`Picture_Category` = 'Interior')
LEFT JOIN 4D_Building_Picts pic_floorplan
    ON (building.`fourd_id` = pic_floorplan.`BUILDING_RecID` AND pic_floorplan.`Picture_Category` = 'Floorplan')
WHERE unit.`id` = 49901
```

Comment: Yup! What I was looking for... however, I get back 4 identical records instead of 1 if all 4 are present... should I just `LIMIT 1` or is there some other optimal thing to do instead?

Comment: I forgot to change the ON clauses to refer to each subtable, so it was duplicating. The issue was that I had `building.fourd_id = picture.BUILDING_RecID` but it should have been `= pic_front.BUILDING_RecID` and so on. The version now should only do once - take a look and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the coalesce function.  It takes multiple fields, and returns the first of them that's non-null.  So something like:

```
Select
  Coalesce(A.Panorama, A.Interior, A.Floorplan, '') as ImagePath
From
  Table A
```

You only end up with one value this way though, which may not actually be what you're after.  If you want all of them I'd suggest using correlated subqueries, like so:

```
Select
  (Select P.Path_To_Picture From 4D_Building_Picts P where P.Building_RecID = B.fourd_Id And P.Picture_Category = 'Front') as Front_Pic,
  (Select P.Path_To_Picture From 4D_Building_Picts P where P.Building_RecID = B.fourd_Id And P.Picture_Category = 'Panorama') as Panamora_Pic,
  (Select P.Path_To_Picture From 4D_Building_Picts P where P.Building_RecID = B.fourd_Id And P.Picture_Category = 'FloorPlan') as FloorPlan_Pic,
  ...
From
  4D_Building B
```

Comment: Yeah, I want multiple values for each possible option. Any other ideas?

Comment: @neezer - I've updated mine to include another option.  It uses correlated subqueries to retrieve the image paths - you can get all the paths as individual columns, but still only get a single record for each building.  I think it may fit your need.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've no clue about performance here, so this is just for my edification: is there any performance hit using nested SELECTs instead of JOINs?

Comment: @neezer - I think you take a minor performance penalty, yes, but if your tables are indexed properly it's typically not significant.  It's definitely a trade off situation - retrieve the fields and keep a single record per building at the expense of some additional table lookups.